# No such file or directory message from bash at terminal start

Tags: command-line

[bash: /opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.11.339/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: No such file or directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMArk.jpg)

```
bash: /opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.11.339/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: No such file or directory
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out where the `/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.11.339/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh` script name was specified, use grep:

```
cd ~/ && grep -nr '/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.11.339/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh'
cd /etc/ && grep -nr '/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.11.339/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh'
cd /opt/ && grep -nr '/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.11.339/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh'
```

There could be files such as `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d/*`, `/etc/environment`, `/etc/environment.d/*`.

Try to comment out such strings in one of these files if you'll find them.

You could also try to create not existent directory structure and an empty file bash complains at:

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.11.339/mkl/bin/
sudo touch /opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.11.339/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh
sudo chmod +x /opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.11.339/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh
```

This is only a workaround to get rid of annoying bash message we don't know where it come from.

Comment: i got this 
.bashrc:17:source /opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.11.339/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64 $*

Comment: source /opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.11.339/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64 $*

Comment: the same problem

Comment: yes always appear when i launch terminal

Comment: ls: cannot access '/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.11.339/mkl/bin/': No such file or directory

Comment: Does `/opt/intel` folder exists?

Comment: no i don't have

Comment: yes sir of course